# How to put a variable in the field line map firebase [nodejs] [js]

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to put a map item in Firebase.
I need to put a field name in a variable.

```
let DocnRef = db.collection('collection').doc('doc');
var ID = "ident1"

DocnRef.update({
                    "notif.{$ID}": "test"

                });
```

but instead of a variable, it turns out like this:
[image]

Help me figure out how to insert a variable into this query.

**UPD**: He asked. He answered.)))

```
var path = "notif."+ID
DocnRef.update({

[path]: 'test',

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
DocnRef.update({
                    [`notif.${ID}`]: "test"

                });
```